# Unknown Move Destination: STORESCP

Tags: java, dcm4che

I have just installed `dcm4chee4-4.4.0.Beta1`, following `INSTALL.md` instructions and everything works fine except `movescu` test.

When I run this test I can see an error in `standalone/log/server.log` (*previously I launched in another console `storescp -b11115`*). This is the error:

```
2015-09-13 12:48:49,105 INFO  [org.dcm4che3.net.Association] (pool-6-thread-7) DCM4CHEE<-MOVESCU(7): processing 1:C-MOVE-RQ[pcid=1, prior=0
  cuid=1.2.840.10008.5.1.4.1.2.2.2 - Study Root Query/Retrieve Information Model - MOVE
  tsuid=1.2.840.10008.1.2 - Implicit VR Little Endian failed. Caused by: org.dcm4che3.net.service.DicomServiceException: Unknown Move Destination: STORESCP@localhost:11115
at org.dcm4chee.archive.retrieve.scp.CMoveSCP.calculateMatches(CMoveSCP.java:184) [dcm4chee-arc-retrieve-scp-4.4.0.Beta1.jar:]
```

I think this is because of configuration, maybe I have to add `STORESCP` as acceptedAET or similar, but I can find info on how to do it. I search through ldap using Apache Directory Studio, but I didn't find anything.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Using dcm4che3, it goes like this if you're implementing an SCP and need to define which other SCPs are allowed to C-STORE things to you.

```
    // Usual calamity creating Connection, ApplicationEntity and Device
    ...
    ApplicationEntity ae = new ApplicationEntity("MYAETITLE");

    String[] acceptedAETs = { "STORESCP", "GEPACS" }; // etc...
    ae.setAcceptedCallingAETitles(acceptedAETs);
```

I assume that your favourite SCP (STORESCP) may need to know where to find the SCP known by MYAETITLE; identified by IP address and port. Typically you connect to an SCP as a SCU, issuing a C-MOVE (in the scenario laid out here) instructing the SCP to do a C-STORE to the AET identified in the C-MOVE.

I'm a bit confused by your choice of AE Title in your question (STORESCP) because that indicates that you kind of mix up the two SCPs involved here; the one receiving the C-MOVE (which should not be called STORESCP :) and the one implementing the C-STORE behaviour. The answer I gave above, is aimed at the SCP implementing the C-STORE behaviour.